# Handle the spacing between elements for a certain condition

Tags: ios, uitableview, feed, spacing

I'm building a FeedViewController for my app.

This screen consists in a tableView (or a collectionView), that shows users' posts. A post always have a content, and it can include or not an image.

**I was wondering what is the best way to handle the case when there is no image to display, how do you handle the height of the table view cell and assure that the spacing between each item remains the same?**

**What I've tried :**

I created a subclass of table view cell and inside I added some constraints. Within the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of my FeedViewController, I added an "if statement" to check whether the postImageView.image is nil or not, and update the height constraint of the post image accordingly. The problem is, as you can see in the screenshot below, the spacing slightly differs from a cell with an image, to a cell without an image. I would like the spacing between elements to be exactly the same, no matters if there's an image attached to the post or not.

How would you guys solve that problem ?

Thanks for your help,

[image: screenshot]

J.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the autolayout then u need to give bottom and top constraints to buttonlabel. OR if you use the autoresizing then you need to fix the position of buttonlabel. @jellyfish6

Comment: Thanks @Vishal, I'm actually using constraints in AutoLayout and tell my view not to create constraints automatically (translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false), and my bottom label does have a bottom and top constraint though, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given BottomConstraint for "Bottom Label" that is the reason why it is having different spacings.
I guess instead of giving bottom constraint provide it with top constraint or both and manage it with priority.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GowthamNamuri ! Could you please explain me further and how to manage the constraints with "priority" ?

Comment: Provide less priority for the bottom constraint than top constraint of button.Basically 1000 will be the highest priority. Whenever conflict occurs then it go with the constraint which has highest priority.Or else you can take an IBOutlet of the constraint and change it's constant accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about the constraints priority and checked it out in the documentation now, it makes a lot of sense ! Coud you please show me an example on how you would apply this concept to my example ? It would help me a lot !

Comment: How you are resizing Cell? to small if there is no image in imageView?.